# Historical arthritis rates for Americans since 1990 to present

Tags: historical

I'm looking for the percent of people with doctor-diagnosed arthritis in America, yearly figures since 1990 to present, or whatever you have in that date range. I'm looking for tabular data.

- I found a [CDC page on arthritis](http://www.cdc.gov/arthritis/data_statistics/) but cannot seem to find historical data.
- I found [this report](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/enhanced/doi/10.1002/art.509) from a long Minnesota study but the data is only from 1955-1994, and 1994 is not new enough to take into account some variables I'm looking at.
- I don't know R and I don't have time to learn it, so things were I have to crunch numbers with more than a spreadsheet do not help me. :(

In return I offer a [Google Docs spreadsheet](https://goo.gl/jCcM6K) with historical data of various diseases, especially inflammatory diseases in the US, since 1990. You may copy it but any changes you make will not be saved in the original.

Thank you! :)

EDIT: I found some more data here.

- [HP2020](https://www.healthypeople.gov/2020/data-search/Search-the-Data?&f[0]=field_topic_area%3A3507). This has more recent data.

Comment: http://wonder.cdc.gov/data2010/focus.htm has *some* of the years you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

hi arthritis questions are available as long-term trends in both brfss and nhis.  run the numbers you want by yourself by directly using the microdata.  here are step-by-step instructions:

http://www.asdfree.com/2012/12/analyze-behavioral-risk-factor.html

http://www.asdfree.com/2012/10/analyzing-national-health-interview.html

Comment: I don't know R, don't have time to learn it, so this does not help me. But thanks. It might help someone else. In a perfect world I'd have infinite time to do infinite things but I don't live in a perfect world.